# Kotlin internal classes in Java visible publicly

Tags: java, android, class, kotlin, public

I am developing an Android [crypto library](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt) in Kotlin. I have a couple of `internal` classes which become publicly visible in a Java app. Found [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html) in documentations.

> `internal` declarations become `public` in Java. Members of `internal` classes go through name mangling, to make it harder to accidentally use them from Java and to allow overloading for members with the same signature that don't see each other according to Kotlin rules;

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: you can down to use *private* visibility. the visibility of top-level types is *package* visibility in Java.

Comment: To maintain the readability of code I can't make them private.

Comment: well. there is no way to prevent the client code using your internal Kotlin classes. `@PublishedApi` only support for warnings, but the client code can forcing to call your internal classes.

Comment: @holi-java That's too bad. Probably will have to sacrifice modularity and make them `private`

Comment: so you should redesign your api. the problem is your design rather than  the visibility. maybe many features can be **private**,  and there is a little features only available in **internal** modules.

Comment: Well, the `internal` modules are supposed to be for internal use only which works perfectly in Kotlin app. There is nothing to be exposed there. The problem is with interoperability from Kotlin to Java and not with the design I believe.

Comment: you should think why the feature must be access round in module. maybe it can be down to the package visibility. I'm not good at English. so I wish you can understand it.

Comment: I understand that making it `private` is the way but the problem is that class is very big and making it inner `class` will further reduce the readability of the `class`.

Comment: @user25 I don't believe that article. It's examples are also not valid. For instance the smart cast error can be solved simply by adding `as Int`.

Comment: I'll try to answer your question of how to redesign your code. do you mind?

Comment: Sure [this](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/blob/master/easycrypt/src/main/java/com/pvryan/easycrypt/symmetric/ECryptSymmetricEncrypt.kt) is the class.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent public visibility of these classes in Java? Does it compromise the security of your library if called from Java, or do you just want not to give any compatibility guaranties for them?

Comment: @Ilya they are there only for internal use and has no purpose of being exposed

Comment: Any solution???

Comment: @vihkat I am now using `internal object` with `@JvmSynthetic internal fun` which does the thing. Check here https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/blob/master/easycrypt/src/main/java/com/pvryan/easycrypt/symmetric/performEncrypt.kt

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have seen all of your [internal  classes](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=path%3Aeasycrypt+internal&type=) are all about [encrypt](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/blob/master/easycrypt/src/main/java/com/pvryan/easycrypt/symmetric/ECryptSymmetric.kt#L142) & [decrypt](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/blob/master/easycrypt/src/main/java/com/pvryan/easycrypt/symmetric/ECryptSymmetric.kt#L212).

you can do it easily by define a top-level function and mark it as  `@JvmSynthetic`, and then makes the [ECryptSymmetricDecrypt](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/blob/master/easycrypt/src/main/java/com/pvryan/easycrypt/symmetric/ECryptSymmetricDecrypt.kt) and [ECryptSymmetricEncrypt](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/blob/master/easycrypt/src/main/java/com/pvryan/easycrypt/symmetric/ECryptSymmetricEncrypt.kt) classes to **private** to prevent Java client access your internal classes, for example:

```
// define this top-level function in your ECryptSymmetricEncrypt.kt

@JvmSynthetic internal fun <T> encrypt(
                                       input:T, password: String, cipher:Cihper, 
                                       erl: ECryptResultListener, outputFile:File,
                                       getKey:(String,ByteArray)->SecretKeySpec){

  ECryptSymmetricEncrypt(input, password, cipher,
                { pass, salt -> getKey(pass, salt) }, erl, outputFile)
}
```

However, it solved your problem, but I still want to say that your code can break into small pieces as further. for example, the encrypt & decrypt algorithm have many duplications, maybe you can applies [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) in your encrypt library & introduce interfaces to make your library explicitly and hiding the `Cipher` operations under the implementation classes. Ideally, the client code can't see any `java.security.*` classes via `Encrypt` or `Decrypt` interfaces. for example:

```
interface Encrypt{
   //          v--- don't include the infrastructure class here,e.g:`Keys`,`Cipher`
   fun encode(...args)
}

interface Decrypt{
   //          v--- don't include the infrastructure class here,e.g:`Keys`,`Cipher`
   fun decode(...args)
}
```

**AND** it is a bad thing that you create an instance and compute the result in `init` block [here](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/blob/master/easycrypt/src/main/java/com/pvryan/easycrypt/symmetric/ECryptSymmetricEncrypt.kt#L38).

**AND** you can use [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to avoid the type checking both in [ECryptSymmetricDecrypt](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/blob/master/easycrypt/src/main/java/com/pvryan/easycrypt/symmetric/ECryptSymmetricDecrypt.kt#L46) and [ECryptSymmetricEncrypt](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/blob/master/easycrypt/src/main/java/com/pvryan/easycrypt/symmetric/ECryptSymmetricEncrypt.kt#L51) classes.

Comment: Using your suggestion of top-level internal function generates an error saying _`internal` function exposes its `private` return type `ECryptSymmetricEncrypt`_.

Comment: @Ryan are you define the top-level function in the related classes?

Comment: @Ryan ooh. I know why. you shouldn't return the `ECryptSymmetricEncrypt` in your top-level function `encrypt`, since it is **private**. you should make the top-level function's return type to `Unit`/ `Any`.

Comment: Yes that solves it. Now how do I call the method from another class?

Comment: @Ryan you should apply the same rule as `encrypt` top-level functions. then in your Kotlin client code you can the top-level function `encrypt` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150503/discussion-between-ryan-and-holi-java).

Answer (score 8):

Apart from `@JvmSynthetic`, you can use `@JvmName` with an illegal Java identifier, like adding a space.

As an example, I added a space in the `@JvmName` param, so any languages except Kotlin will not be able to invoke your method:

```
@JvmName(" example")
internal fun example() {
}
```

Comment: that seems so awful, but clever and technically solves the problem so upvoted ;)

Comment: @ChelseaUrquhart Cheers :-)

Comment: @ice1000 Geniuss!!

Answer (score 2):

As per my answer on this question in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62951988/11326621) thread:

Not perfect solution but I found two hacky solutions

#### Annotate every public method of that `internal class` by `@JvmName` with blank spaces or special symbols by which it'll generate syntax error in Java.

For e.g.

```
internal class LibClass {

    @JvmName(" ") // Blank Space will generate error in Java
    fun foo() {}

    @JvmName(" $#") // These characters will cause error in Java
    fun bar() {}
}
```

Since this above solution isn't appropriate for managing huge project or not seems good practice, this below solution might help.

#### Annotate every public method of that `internal class` by `@JvmSynthetic` by which public methods aren't accessible by Java.

For e.g.

```
internal class LibClass {

    @JvmSynthetic
    fun foo() {}

    @JvmSynthetic
    fun bar() {}
}
```

## Note:

This solution protects the methods/fields of the function. As per the question, it does not hide the visibility of class in Java. So the perfect solution to this is still awaited.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing a private constructor + companion object containing method to instantiate annotated with JvmSynthetic preserves encapsulation.

```
// Private constructor to inhibit instantiation
internal class SomeInternalClass private constructor() {

    // Use the companion object for your JvmSynthetic method to
    // instantiate as it's not accessible from Java
    companion object {
        @JvmSynthetic
        fun instantiate(): SomeInternalClass =
            SomeInternalClass()
    }

    // This is accessible from Java
    @JvmSynthetic
    internal var someVariable1 = false

    // This is accessible from Java
    @JvmSynthetic
    var someVariable2 = false



    // This is inaccessible, both variable and methods.
    private var someVariable3 = false
    @JvmSynthetic
    fun getSomeVariable3(): Boolean =
        someVariable3
    @JvmSynthetic
    fun setSomeVariable3(boolean: Boolean) {
        someVariable3 = boolean
    }
}
```