# How to hide visibility of Kotlin internal class in Java from different modules?

Tags: android, class, kotlin, internals, modifier

I was working on the Android library which I'm developing in Kotlin. I kept access modifier of some classes as `internal`. Internal classes are only visible in that library module in Kotlin. If I implement that library in the app then it's not visible at all.

But the problem comes when accessing that library from Java code. If I create `.java` file and type name of that `internal` class of library then IDE is suggesting name and it's resolved and compiled without any error.

For e.g.

### **Library Module:**

```kotlin
internal class LibClass {
    // Fields and Methods
}
```

---

*After implementing above library in **DemoApp module:***

### App Module

Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun stuff() {
    val lib = LibClass() // Error.. Not resolving
}
```

Java:

```java
public void stuff() {
    LibClass lib = new LibClass() // Successfully resolving and compiling
}
```

So that's the problem. How can I achieve securing that class from Java?

Thank you!

Comment: This should not be the case, in my IDE I cant compile it.
Are you sure you are accessing LibClass in app module?

Comment: Yes I can access it from app module. It's just showing red error underline below class name but compiling successfully

Comment: Not sure whether it would work, but maybe try annotating your class with `@JvmName` and give it an invalid Java name like containing a space, hyphen or something.

Comment: Okay. I'll try this and will let you know about it

Comment: @SaurabhThorat I tried using `@JvmName` but it's not working. It only works when top-level functions are created inside `.kt` file. It's not working for the class.

Comment: Checkout this answer... May be useful... Think @JvmSynthetic solves it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393423/kotlin-internal-classes-in-java-visible-publicly

Comment: You could use [`@RestrictTo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/RestrictTo.Scope) annotation and set the scope to your library only.

Comment: `@RestrictTo` annotation only shows a warning. It still compiles successfullt

Comment: @Robin `@JvmSynthetic` annotation is not targetted for class. So we can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not perfect solution but I found two hacky solutions

#### Annotate every public method of that `internal class` by `@JvmName` with blank spaces or special symbols by which it'll generate syntax error in Java.

For e.g.

```
internal class LibClass {

    @JvmName(" ") // Blank Space will generate error in Java
    fun foo() {}

    @JvmName(" $#") // These characters will cause error in Java
    fun bar() {}
}
```

Since this above solution isn't appropriate for managing huge project or not seems good practice, this below solution might help.

#### Annotate every public method of that `internal class` by `@JvmSynthetic` by which public methods aren't accessible by Java.

For e.g.

```
internal class LibClass {

    @JvmSynthetic
    fun foo() {}

    @JvmSynthetic
    fun bar() {}
}
```

## Note:

This is explained in detail in [this article](https://medium.com/scalereal/hide-internal-members-of-kotlin-module-from-jvm-c7730507fb17).

Comment: but what if the library itself has a mix of Kotlin and Java and Java  consumes Kotlin code using `@file:JvmName("SomeName")`. Set blank or `#$` makes them inaccessible for library's java classes as well. How to get around this?

Comment: @GopalSAkshintala Then it's not appropriate. Either make it with 100% Kotlin or Java (as far as I know).

Answer (score 2):

I see you have got class with internal modifier that cannot be instantiated in kotlin class but can be instantiated in Java file.
If it’s a standalone class, you can make its constructor private and allow the instantiation using a static method (Companion object).

Comment: Thanks. But if I make it private then I can't access it from other kotlin classes too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide visibility of the class instead of each functions or fields, you can use `@file:JvmSynthetic` on top of your class.

E.g.

```
@file:JvmSynthetic
package  com.example.app

internal class LibClass {
    var count: Int = 0

    internal fun exampleFun() {
        
    }
}
```